# Mysql obtener el siguiente lunes a medio dia

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Hola amigos me podrian ayudar con lo siguiente:
Tengo un campo con fecha en formato timestamp y quisiera saber como obtener el siguiente lunes a medio dia para guardarlo en `date_end`.

```
journay     date_start  date_end
1           1515200400  1515369600
2           1515805200  1515974400
3           1516410000  1516579200
4           1517014800  1517184000
5           1517619600  1517788800
```

tengo el siguiente query en el que si obtengo el lunes pero a las 6pm y lo quisiera a medio dia es decir a las 12:00pm

```
select journay, DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(max(date_game_large)), INTERVAL (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(max(date_game_large)))=1, 8, DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(max(date_game_large))))) DAY) as NEXTMONDAY from tablaone GROUP by journay order by journay


id_competition  journay .   date_start  date_end
385 1   1515200400  2018-01-08 18:00:00
385 2   1515805200  2018-01-15 18:00:00
385 3   1516410000  2018-01-22 18:00:00
385 4   1517014800  2018-01-29 18:00:00
385 5   1517619600  2018-02-05 18:00:00
```

me podrian ayudar por favor

Comment: puedes pasar la estructura de tu bd? Para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(
        ADDDATE(
            FROM_UNIXTIME(date_game_large),
            7-WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_game_large))
        ),
        '%Y-%m-%d 12:00:00'
    ) AS NEXTMONDAY
FROM tablaone
```

Funciones que usamos:

- `FROM_UNIXTIME`: Convierte tu timestamp a datetime.
- `WEEKDAY`: Devuelve en número el día de la semana (lunes 0, martes 1...)
- `ADDDATE`: Agrega el número de días que le indicas a la fecha dada.

  En este punto agregamos a la fecha una semana menos el `WEEKDAY` de la fecha. De este modo, si tenemos una fecha que es lunes le añadimos 7 días (7-0), si es martes 6 días (7-1), si es miércoles 5 días (7-2)...
- `DATE_FORMAT`: Da el formato propuesto a tu campo.
  Aquí es donde le indicamos que quieres que siempre ponga como hora las 12:00:00

Comment: gracias me ayudo mucho saludos